# AWS Free Tier Alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, alert, amazon-rds

So I'm receiving this alert at the end of every month for the past year. 
[image]
And rightly so in my cost & Bills Dashboard there it is:
[image: this alert]

But each month I go in RDS Dashboard and it is empty, I checked every tab and didn't found anything.

[image]

Could that be a glitch ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check all regions. Your screenshot only shows US East.

Comment: did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is because AWS count this if how long your AWS instance is running other than other factors.

For RDS the maximum amount of time an instance can run is 750 hours which usually cover a complete month of 31 days.

Normally you use *30 = 720 (744 in the case of 31 days) hours so AWS wore you if your free tier is about to exceed.

if you calculate then it would be about the % showing by the console.

Comment: I understand how the AWS Free Tier alerts system works, my question was "why can't I find the instance running in my dashboard, as mentioned in the alert"